# KQL join two tables with different TimeStamp

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I´m working with KQL and trying to join two tables on a timestamp field. The problem is that they have different values when it comes to seconds.

The table "TableToJoin" will ingest record every minute (so seconds are 00) and the MeasureTime column I made will have different seconds depending on when I hit the run button (knowing it will starting counting 36h from now)

Do you know a method I could use to fix this?

I paste my code below:

```
range MeasureTime from ago(36h) to now() step(10m) 
| join kind=rightouter 
(TableToJoin| where TagName == 'TagName') on $left.MeasureTime == $right.Timestamp | take 10
```

TableToJoin TimeStamp:

```
2021-11-01T14:09:00Z
2021-11-01T14:08:00Z
2021-11-01T14:06:00Z
2021-11-01T14:05:00Z
2021-11-01T14:04:00Z
2021-11-01T14:03:00Z
2021-11-01T14:02:00Z
2021-11-01T14:01:00Z
2021-11-01T14:00:00Z
```

MeasureTime TimeStamp:

```
2021-11-01T13:59:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:00:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:01:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:02:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:03:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:04:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:05:20.5230363Z
2021-11-01T14:06:20.5230363Z
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bin() function to "round" the timestamp. For example:

```
range MeasureTime from ago(36h) to now() step(10m) 
| extend MeasureTime = bin(MeasureTime, 10s)
| join kind=rightouter (
    TableToJoin| where TagName == 'TagName'
) on $left.MeasureTime == $right.Timestamp | take 10
```

Comment: Thanks @Avnera. I was able to solve it changing the ago() and now() with datetime() using a date with 00.00 seconds

Comment: Cool Sean. I added an example for it, it might be more general since you do not need to provide fixed "datetimes" and can use the relative datetime functions.